# Sorry, Ubuntu 18.04 has experienced an internal error

Tags: nvidia, kernel, xubuntu, 18.04

So I just bought a new computer, this is it: https://msi.com/Laptop/GL63-8RD.html

I installed Xubuntu 18.04 LTS on it using a bootable USB, and I selected all the options to download updates and third party software because I know Nvidia graphics can be finicky. Everything seemed fine when I was trying the OS with the USB, but after installing the problems started.

I boot into the OS just fine, insert the password to unlock the disk and then my user password normally. Then after logging in if I try to open something like the terminal or the web browser the OS crashes without warning, and then I can move the mouse but nothing else, if I click on an icon with the mouse nothing happens, I can't open the terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T and can't shutdown with Alt+F4, only thing I can do is move the mouse and shutdown the computer by manually pressing the power button for a few seconds. I then tried to boot into the OS and not open anything, just to see if it crashes, and it did but this time it gave me a nice error message. These are the details:

**Package**

linux-image-4.15.0-22-generic 4.15.0-22.24

**ProblemType**

KernelOops

**Title**

watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU #6 stuck for 23s! [gvfs-mtp-volume:1639]

**Annotation**

Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.

**ApportVersion**

2.20.9-0ubuntu7

**Architecture**

amd64

**Dependencies**

There are many, they are in the pictures here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq7GB.jpg

**DistroRelease**

Ubuntu 18.04

**Failure**

Oops

**InstallationDate**

Installed on 2018-06-03 (0 days ago)

**InstallationMedia**

Xubuntu 18.04 LTS "Bionic Beaver" - Release amd64(20180426)

**OopsText**

In the pictures: 
https://pastebin.com/aEBh8VuZ (sorry for some reason imgur wasn't working with these pictures, and the site doesn't let me post more than 8 links)

**PackageArchitecture**

amd64

**ProcCpuinfoMinimal**

In the pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUM6L.jpg

**ProcVersionSignature**

Ubuntu 4.15.0-22.24-generic 4.15.17

**SourcePackage**

linux-signed

**Tags**

kernel-oops bionic

**Uname**

Linux 4.15.0-22-generic x86_64

**UpgradeStatus**

No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)

After I sent the report, I couldn't do anything with the computer. By the way, while I was typing this there were like 4 or 5 other errors saying "System program problem detected", but I didn't open them and now there is a new error message but when I press Report Problem with the mouse it doesn't respond.

What can I do? Right now I can't do anything with the OS, it crashes every single time I boot after just a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The problem had to do with the Nvidia graphics card. I edited the boot options and added nomodeset and now I can login and use the computer, but the graphics are not very good (everything seems to be zoomed in, I can't see the full display in my screen). I think that now I have to install some proprietary Nvidia drivers and remove nomodeset to make everything work like it is supposed to, but I'm not sure what drivers I am supposed to install or how. Once I figure it out I'll update the answer.